# Merge two associative arrays sharing keys and concatenate string values

Tags: php, arrays, merge, concatenation, associative-array

I have two arrays:

```
$arr1 = array("123" => "abc");

$arr2 = array("123" => "xyz", "456" => "lmn");
```

I want the resultant array to be:

`$arr = array("123" => "abc,xyz", "456" => "lmn");`

I know I can write some code to fetch the values corresponding to keys and then concat with a separator like ';' or ',', but I want to know is there any efficient way to do this?
An in-built function maybe?

Comment: @VishnuBhadoriya: array_merge_recursive will not work with integer indexes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple foreach will do! Check inline comments

```
$arr1 = ["123" => "abc"];

$arr2 = ["123" => "xyz", "456" => "lmn"];

foreach ($arr2 as $key => $value) {
    if(array_key_exists($key, $arr1)) // Check if key exists in array
        $arr1[$key] .= ",$value";     // If so, append
    else
        $arr1[$key] = $value;         // otherwise, add
}

print_r($arr1);
```

**Prints**

```
Array
(
    [123] => abc,xyz
    [456] => lmn
)
```

Check this [Eval](https://eval.in/719026)

Comment: Thanks! but i was looking for something more like array_merge() so that I don't have to write this additional code.

Comment: @Tha all eval.in demo links are now deadends.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$arr1 = array("123" => "abc");

$arr2 = array("123" => "xyz", "456" => "lmn");

$o = [];
foreach($arr1 as $k => $v)
{
    $o[$k][] = $v;
}
foreach($arr2 as $k => $v)
{
    $o[$k][] = $v;
}
$result = array_map(function($v){implode(',', array_unique($v));}, $o);
```

Comment: This unexplained answer is using too many loops.

Comment: Can you show a answer without two loop?

Comment: ...the accepted answer.  Also, I don't see where `array_unique()` is asked for.

Comment: Your answer, for the record, is using more than 2 loops.  There are two `foreach()` loops then two functional iterators inside of a `array_map()` loop.